# UILabel.text updates out of sync from Socket.io emit

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io, uilabel

I have implemented a simple node.js server with socket.io. The server emits a message at intervals. The iOS client receives the socket.io message from the server and processes the data however the subsequent update to the UILabel.text happens out of synch. For example, the client can receive  the following values [1,2,3,4,5] and the value 1 will not be displayed until the server has emitted 2 and the value 2 will not be displayed until the server has emitted 3 and so on and so on.

Here is the iOS code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var testLbl: UILabel!

let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "https://localhost:3000")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
var socket:SocketIOClient?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    socket = manager.socket(forNamespace: "/namespace")
    socket?.joinNamespace()
    addHandler()
    socket?.connect()
}


func addHandler () {
    socket.on("incoming", callback: { (dataArray, ack) in
        var responseData = dataArray[0] as? [[String:String]]
        var responesDataIter = responseData![0].makeIterator()
        var xx: String = "" 
        while let xx = responesDataIter.next() {
            item = xx.value
        }

        self.testLbl.text! = item
    })
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Implement acknowledge functionality, unless you get an ack from client, don't emit again.

Comment: Hi Sharad, thank you for your reply but I do not think implementing acknowledge functionality will update the UILabel any quicker as the client already has the value. I believe this is a threading issue so I've added DispatchQueue.main.async to my code and I still get the same outcome.